# How can an electric current flow between the end of the channel and drain?

Tags: electric-circuits, semiconductor-physics

In my book, it explains why current can flow even if the channel ends:

[image]

The device still conducts: as illustrated in figure, once the electrons reach the end of the channel, they experience the high electric field in the depletion region surrounding the drain junction and are rapidly swept to the drain terminal.

I can't understand this explanation.

There isn't any carrier between the end of the channel and the drain. According to the microscopic model of electric current, i=nAqvd
, there isn't any current because there isn't any carrier.

I want to be clear about the electric field in the depletion region.

Is the electric field in the depletion region stronger than the field in the channel?

If so, can you explain the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There isn't any carrier between the end of the channel and the drain

The carriers are injected from the source. An electron travels from the source, through the channel, into the drain.

> I want to be clear about the electric field in the depletion region.

> Is the electric field in the depletion region stronger than the field in the channel?

It depends on where you are in the depletion region. The field in the depletion region is not a constant.

The fields are in different directions. In the channel the field is vertical, when approaching the drain it is horizontal.

Comment: *Beside* the channel the field is vertical. *In* the channel, the field is horizontal, sufficient to drive ohmic conduction, fairly small. In the depletion zone, the field is larger.

Comment: @JohnDoty Is that true? If we just had a MOS cap the field would be vertical at the surface in inversion. Does adding a source and drain change that? I can understand it might not be entirely vertical, but there is a vertical piece, no? Maybe I'm underestimating that horizontal component...

Comment: If you just have a MOS cap, the inversion layer is at constant potential, so the field is zero within it. If there's a field in the inversion layer, it drives a current, since the inversion layer has free carriers available.

Comment: The field in the channel (outside the depletion region) is mostly vertical. This is the basis of the gradual channel approximation. This is not in conflict with the fact that potential is constant *along* the channel in a MOS capacitor (or when $V_{DS} = 0$).